# How to implement created vs updated in an RSS feed

Tags: rss, feed

I'd like to implement an RSS feed that has items that have distinguishable *created* and *updated* dates.

I have a custom application that can display the difference, but I'd like "normal" RSS readers to fall back to the updated date.

I could subvert `<pubDate>` and `<dc:date>` to be one and the other, but feedvalidator.org informs that the both shouldn't be used at the same time.

Is there a namespace I could include that distinguishes between created and updated dates?  Or am I forced to create my own?

What are the implications of creating your own namespace for custom fields?

Comment: Don't think you can have an updated node unless you republish, spike the older version and include a new posting date

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering this myself. Atom feeds distinguish between created and updated, and atom elements can be included in rss2. So what you can do, is add an atom namespace, and then add in 
2011-11-04T19:54:53Z

I don't know if this is supported by any readers, but it complies with standards, and gives the option to distinguish between the two.